# Haskell type signature with composite/multi-param type constructors

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I've discovered these kinds of type signatures:

```
x :: a b -> Int
x f = 3

y :: a b c -> Int
y f = 3

z :: a b c d -> Int
z f = 3

> x [1] -- 3
> y (1, 2) -- 3
> z (1, 2, 3) -- 3
```

Basically:

1. x only accepts a value inhabiting a type constructor with 1 parameter or more.
2. y only accepts a value inhabiting a type constructor with 2 parameters or more.
3. z only accepts a value inhabiting a type constructor with 3 parameters or more.

They are valid, but I'm not sure what they mean nor what they could be used for.

They seem related to polytypic notions or polymorphism over type constructors, but enforce an invariant based on many parameters the type constructor accepts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without further constraints, such types are useless – there's nothing you could really do with them, expect pass them right on. But that's actually the same situation with a signature `a -> Int`: if nothing is known about `a`, there's nothing you can do with it either!

However, like with e.g. `toInteger :: Integral a => a -> Integer`, adding constraints to the arguments allows you to do stuff. For instance,

```
import Data.Foldable
import Prelude hiding (foldr)

x' :: (Foldable a, Integral b) => a b -> Integer
x' = foldr ((+) . toInteger) 0
```

Rather more often than not, when you have a type of the form `a b ... n o p q`, then `a b ... p` is at least an instance of the `Functor` class, often also `Applicative` and `Monad`; sometimes `Foldable`, `Traversable`, or `Comonad`; sometimes `a b ... o` will be `Arrow`... These constraints allow you to do quite a lot with the composite types, without knowing what particular type constructors you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks! That made sense, but could you also explain why `a b` works for Type constructors of 1 parameter or *more* and `a b c` works for type constructors of 2 parameters or *more*. (Emphasis is on the *more*) How does it know that extra parameters still satisfy the type rules?

Comment: Erm... it _doesn't_ work, not in the sense that you could write signatures like, say, `Either Int -> String`: every argument / result of a function must have kind `*`, but `Either Int :: * -> *`. So... what do you mean?

Comment: Ok, to make this a bit clearer. I'm confused as to what exactly `a b c` is. Is it `a (b c)` or `a (b (c))`? How does it choose? Furthermore, it seems that a signature like `fn :: (TC b) => a b -> Int` accepts `(1, X)` and `(1, 2, X)` and `("string", "string", "string", X)` as long as X is constrained by TC. Why are all these types valid? I tried it in GHCI, and I could keep running `fn blah` where blah is all of those types I wrote above.

Comment: Also I didn't understand your last paragraph "Rather more often than not... "

Comment: Ah. Well, types are _parsed_ exactly the same way as expressions, i.e. `a b c` means `(a b) c`, i.e. `a` isn't literally a function of two type arguments: it's curried – a function of one type variable, yielding a function of of another type argument, yielding a type. So `a b c` is simply a special case of `d c`, with `d ~ a b`; in particular, `(Int,Int,a) ~ (,,) Int Int a ~ t a` with `t ~ (Int, Int, )`.

Comment: With “rather more often than not” I meant that most useful type constructors in Haskell are actually functors, so you can generally use at least that class (often also more powerfule ones) when writing functions that are polymorphic on an `* -> *` argument.

Answer (score 0):

After studying @leftaroundabout answer and experimenting in GHCI, I've come to an understanding with composite types. Their unification with applied types is based on both the evaluation order and their type variable's kind signature. The evaluation order is quite important as `a b c ~ (((a) b) c)` while `a (b c)` is `(a ((b) c)`. This makes `a b c` match composite types where `a` is matched with type constructors of kind `* -> * -> *`, and `a b` with `* -> *` and `a b c` with `*`.

I explained it fully with diagrams and GHCI code in this gist (https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/2a1d3ecb67dcdabfc7e0) (it's too long for stack overflow)